# how to find maximum path sum between any two nodes in a bst?

Tags: tree, max, binary-search-tree, nodes

How can we find the maximum possible path sum between any two elements in a binary search tree?
I am not just talking about any two leaf nodes. This question is inclusive of all nodes.
And by path sum i mean the sum of all the data elements in a path.

Comment: Can you describe path? Do you mean "a chain of parents"?

Comment: Path means the distance from one node to another. And path sum means the sum of data elements in the path.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the question but does the path need to include unique nodes only, because if not the answer would be infinite. If it is unique wouldn't the max equal the min?

Comment: Yeah the path needs to include unique nodes only. And for any two nodes we will have only one path. Here we need to find the maximum of such unique paths in a bst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pseudo code:

```
Set maxSum = MINVALUE

TreeMaxSum (tree)
   maxLeft = TreeMaxSum(tree->left)
   maxRight = TreeMaxSum(tree->right)
   maxSum = max(maxSum, maxLeft+maxRight+tree->value)
   return max(maxLeft, maxRight) + tree->value

TreeMaxSum(tree)
```

Of course you need to take care of usual edge cases and "empty leaf" values...